# How to Sum Entire Column with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to Sum an entire column in SQL. The code below sums each row, but instead I just want a total row. My guess is it has to be done with GROUP BY, but the only way the query works is if I use Share_Type or Balance, neither of which sums the column. I also tried adding the CASE statement to the Group by (by leaving off 'AS MoneyMaxBalance" but I get an error message.

```
SELECT
      CASE
          WHEN SHARE_TYPE = 57 THEN SUM(BALANCE) ELSE 0 
      END AS MoneyMaxBalance
FROM SHARE
          INNER JOIN ACCOUNT ON SHARE.MEMBER_NBR = ACCOUNT.MEMBER_NBR AND 
                                SHARE.SHARE_NBR = ACCOUNT.ACCOUNT_NBR
          INNER JOIN PRODUCT ON ACCOUNT.PRODUCT_CODE = PRODUCT.PRODUCT_CODE
GROUP BY  SHARE_TYPE
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want one row, don't use `group by`:

```
SELECT SUM(BALANCE) AS MoneyMaxBalance
FROM SHARE s INNER JOIN
     ACCOUNT a
     ON s.MEMBER_NBR = a.MEMBER_NBR AND 
        s.SHARE_NBR = a.ACCOUNT_NBR INNER JOIN
    PRODUCT p
    ON a.PRODUCT_CODE = p.PRODUCT_CODE
WHERE SHARE_TYPE = 57;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN SHARE_TYPE = 57 THEN BALANCE ELSE 0 END) AS MoneyMaxBalance
FROM SHARE s 
INNER JOIN ACCOUNT a ON s.MEMBER_NBR = a.MEMBER_NBR AND s.SHARE_NBR = a.ACCOUNT_NBR 
INNER JOIN PRODUCT p ON a.PRODUCT_CODE = p.PRODUCT_CODE
```

Hope this Query Works fine for your case:

Comment: Kinldy Share your comments-- @user9762321